# Apache VirtualHost multiple transport protocols

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to use a VirtualHost on my server with mod_proxy to add an authentication layer to another server I am running. The authentication and basic loading work correctly, but a main page requires the use of a different layer 5 protocol, ws:// instead of http://. In the ProxyPass(Reverse) directives, I must supply the layer 5 protocol to use. I have tried not supplying the protocol, supplying two different virtualhosts with the different protocols in the opening tag, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost http://192.168.192.172:5440>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost ws://192.168.192.172:5440>
```

both of which fail on loading the server. Is there another directive I can add, or a different way of setting up the VirtualHost that will instead work?
My current VirtualHost config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:5440>
    ProxyPass / "http://192.168.192.172:8080"
    ProxyPassReverse / "http://192.168.192.172:8080"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Virtualhost does not work with full url scheme as in your first two examples, Virtualhost just takes ip:port or *:port  or even *default*:port, but don't use names or full url schemes.

Correct examples:

```
<Virtualhost 192.168.192.172:5440>
<Virtualhost 192.168.192.172:5440 192.168.192.172:5441>
<Virtualhost *:5440>
<VirtualHost _default_:5440>
```

In the last virtualhost you need to match slashes in ProxyPass, if there is a ending slash in the source, add it to the target, if there is not, don't:

```
ProxyPass / http://192.168.192.172:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.192.172:8080/
```

or

```
ProxyPass /something http://192.168.192.172:8080/something
```

As for ws, use [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)

for example:

```
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://192.168.192.172/
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://192.168.192.172/
```

Comment: Thanks! Informative. but did not solve the problem. It did send me in the right direction, even though I have not solved my issue yet.